# Viewport width in jQuery not working?

Tags: jquery

So I used this snippet I found online to show the Menu ID upon scrolling 200px down. I do however want to keep this ID hidden for mobile users, so I am looking for a way to include viewport widths in the if conditions.

```
(function($) {
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 200 && $( window ).width > 980) {
            $('#menu').fadeIn(500);
            console.log($( window ).width());
        } else {
            $('#menu').fadeOut(500);
        }
    });
});
```

I've found online that you can use multiple conditions by using '&&' after your first condition. Using the console.log line I checked the value it would give me on a mobile device and applied it to the conditions, however it doesn't seem to work. It will always show the menu upon scrolling down, logging the width to the console each time.

Would this be the right way to approach this issue? Or perhaps I need a different function for viewport widths and call this function?

Comment: The right way depends on what your mobile users need and on what sized device?

Answer (score 0):

I've just used this in the past:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    if ($(window).innerWidth() < 568) {
        $('#menu').fadeOut(500);
    } else {
        $('#menu').fadeIn(500);
    }

});
```